# Sublime Text 2 code snippet not working in proper scope

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I have just written the following snippet, and saved it in the folder Packages/User/HTML as "add-script-source.sublime-snippet."

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript" src="${1:script.js}">${2}</script>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>scriptsrc</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Now, I only want this snippet to work in HTML files, but it does not. If I comment out the "scope" tag, it will work in JavaScript, but still not in HTML. I was under the impression that the name of the folder beneath your User folder also gave Sublime Text the appropriate scope (as stated in this video https://tutsplus.com/lesson/your-first-snippet/), this does not appear to do anything. Whenever I set the scope tag to ANYTHING, the snippet does not trigger.

What might the problem be?

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me.  Are you sure you are setting the file to `HTML` in the bottom right corner of ST2?

Comment: Maybe you have a conflict with another package. Try disabling any HTML related package (such as Zen coding) and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, it appears as though it IS working, just the helpful sublime text autocomplete doesn't appear, as it does in other languages. Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> "just the helpful sublime text autocomplete doesn't appear, as it does
>   in other languages. Does anyone know why this might be?"

You need to add this to your `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file.

```
 "auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
```

Then give it a description in the snippet file:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript" src="${1:script.js}">${2}</script>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>scriptsrc</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>scriptsrc</description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. In JavaScript it automatically creates the description from the file name. I don't know why it would be different in HTML.

Comment: Added the solution to my post.

Comment: BAM! That's it! Now can you explain to me why "source - comment" doesn't apply to HTML?

Comment: @mysteryDate, I am not certain, but it seems that the default in ST2 is to only show autocomplete popups when the scope is `source.something`.  Adding that line to your settings file allows popups to appear for text and source scopes.

Comment: thnaks @AGS, it was very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I was facing the same problem and if not for your post would never have figured it out.