# Auto Complete Comment Blocks in CSS using Sublime Text

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext

In a js file, I can type `comm` and autocomplete will kick in prompting me for comment blocks. This functionality doesn't work in CSS files.

I thought this would be the answer for me but it is not.

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
```

This post also looked promising, but it was not either. 
[Sublime Text 2 code snippet not working in proper scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495269/sublime-text-2-code-snippet-not-working-in-proper-scope)

Anyone know of a way to add it or to turn it on for CSS?

Comment: Here is a video of what I'm referring to: http://youtu.be/c7ZQ_AhfEIw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a snippet that whos scope has CSS files included. Example:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * ${1:CSS Section}
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>comm</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.css</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save this file with the .sublime-snippet extension in your User packages folder (Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Browse Packages) and you will be good to go.

In a CSS file, you would then type "comm" and hit tab.

NOTE: The folder location I mention above is for Mac users FYI